# Anyway to scale a cloud service in the preview portal?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

It seems like there is no option to do that? The only way to get this done is through the old site?

Comment: Was the cloud service created in the new or old portal?

Comment: It is created through the old management portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - there's not.

You have to go to the old portal: https://manage.windowsazure.com.

-Mikkel

Answer (score 0):

[image: IaaS scaling]

It does not show any scaling option..